# "<p:message" Não Apresenta Mensagem no XHTML

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Olá, estou implementando um cadastro utilizando o primefaces para apresentar as mensagens críticas realizadas no bean.
Estou utilizando o FacesContext conforme abaixo:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", mensagem));
```

A mensagem é inserida e aprestnada no log do servidor de aplicação, porém com um warning:

```
WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed
```

E log abaixo são listadas as mensagens das criticas, por exemplo:

```
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(), detail=(Nome não preenchido!)]
```

Alguém saberia informar o que pode ser?
Obrigado

Comment: Como você esta chamando a mensagem no xhtml?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa capturar essas mensagens na tela:

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" ></p:messages>
```